# Why can you reassign value to modules?

Tags: python, module, python-2.7

In Python, why can you reassign values for modules when you can't reassign anything for functions?

Is it because modules are pre-written scripts and you're simply editing those scripts when you do commands like this?

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log = 1
>>> math.log
1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python (unlike, e.g. Java and alike) `import module` is rather a command than a declaration, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
math = __import__('math', globals(), locals(), [], -1)
```

So, here we load a module `math` and assign a reference to it to the variable `math`.
Now, since modules are objects too, you can re-assign any attribute in them (you're not editing the script by that). Needless to say, that's a highly unrecommended thing to do.